# Is there a solid way to top align labels to their controls?

Tags: asp.net, css, label

I'm looking for a straight forward css solution that will force labels to top align with their controls in asp. So for example:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="cboBox" Text="Control Label" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cboBox" />
```

Would appear something like:

```
Control Label
[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]V
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them both in a span or div:

```
<span class="field">
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="cboBox" Text="Control Label" />
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cboBox" />
</span>
```

Then:

```
.field label,
.field select
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;

    /* achieves same as inline-block for IE7 */
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working. The label is still to the left of the control

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit, my answer only deals with the top alignment.  You could float the select left, that would do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting them in a container, and apply specific styling for spans within that container. The example below might need a little tweaking, but it should point you in the right direction:

```
div.container span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
div.container input {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

And then on the page:

```
<div class="container">
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="cboBox" Text="Control Label" />
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cboBox" />    
</div>
```