# Unable to set span & elements within it to the top of the div

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am trying to get a span and the elements within it to sit at the top of the div the span is in.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MOHSAIC.master.vb" Inherits="NewMOHSAIC.MOHSAIC" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>MOHSAIC</title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link href="../Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="../Content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <header class="container-fluid darkHeader">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10 leftDiv">
                        <img class="dhssImageStyle" src="../Content/images/DHSSLogo_blue.gif" alt="DHSS Logo"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 rightDiv" style="background-color:aqua">
                        <span class="field">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUsernameDesc" runat="server">Username:</asp:Label>&nbsp;
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server">&nbsp;placeholder</asp:Label>&nbsp;                       
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlSignOut" runat="server" NavigateUrl="SignOut.aspx" Target="_top">Sign Out</asp:HyperLink> 
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAgencyDesc" runat="server">Agency:</asp:Label>&nbsp;
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAgency" runat="server">placeholder</asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSelectAgency" runat="server" CssClass="DarkHeader" Visible="False">Select</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAgency" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnChangeAgency" runat="server" CssClass="DarkHeader"> Change</asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDatabaseHdr" runat="server">DataBase:</asp:Label>&nbsp;
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDatabase" runat="server">placeholder</asp:Label>&nbsp;
                        </span>
                    </div>               
                </div>
            </header>
......
```

Per this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945632/is-there-a-solid-way-to-top-align-labels-to-their-controls) I did the following with my CSS:

```
.field label,
.field a,
.field select,
.field linkButton {    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

But it's had no effect. I tried adding the contents of the span one-by-one but none of them work.

Here's an image of what it looks like. I have the background color set to aqua because it helps me see what the div is doing.

[image]

I have a sneaking suspicion that it actually is working and everything is sitting at the top of the div like I want but that the dark blue above the aqua for some reason is not part of the div. I tried using height: 100% in my div, thinking that would increase the height of the div but it does not.

Comment: Did you know your browser has a pretty advanced Developer Console hidden behind the F12 key? You can inspect and edit HTML, CSS, and JavaScript there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had an extra row that I didn't need. Once removed it worked properly